# Multiple Params in get Django url regex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I need to pass two params in the url :
eg : http://127.0.0.1:8000/events/103,104/3/

here

- param1 = 103,104
- param2 = 3

The url patterm I used :

```
url(r'^events/(?P<categories_string>[^\/]*)/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$','main.views.events'),
```

I also tried :

```
url(r'^events/(?P<categories_string>.*)/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$','main.views.events'),
```

My View.py:

```
def events(request, categories_string='', page_no=1):
    if categories_string =='':
        return render(request, "main/events.html", {'message' : 'string is null'})
    return render(request, "main/events.html", { 'message': {'cat' : categories_string, 'pg' : page_no}})
```

And my output is :

```
{'cat': '103,104/3', 'pg': 1}
```

This is my second day working with Django and I would appreciate if I am guided to good reference to read about practices to allow multiple params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems most likely that your Regex is matching `103,104/3` with `.*`. Assuming your cat input is always like `digits,digits` then the following should work:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<categories_string>\d+,\d+)/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$','main.views.events'),
```

Comment: Actually cat input is digits OR digits, digits OR digits,digits,digits and so on... so based on your answer I used this : it seems to work url(r'^events/(?P<categories_string>[\d+,]+)/(?P<page_no>\d+)/$','main.views.events'),